# Removing cruft lines with sed

Tags: regex, sed

How can you write a single sed command that will remove lines that contain any of several regular expressions?

For example I want sed to remove "/./. ::", ":: *", "::foo*", and "^^bar" from a document.

As of now, when I run

```
 sed -ir '/ "//.//. ::|:: _|::foo_|^^bar" /d' text.file
```

the response is "unknown command '/'".

This is the case with or without the inner "s around the regex:

```
 sed -ir '/ //.//. ::|:: _|::foo_|^^bar /d' text.file
```

Also if I remove the escape(/) before the '/' such as:

```
 sed -ir '/ "/./. ::|:: _|::foo_|^^bar" /d' text.file
```

the return becomes "unknown command '.'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the escape symbol: `\`
And there's no need to quote the pattern match or add underscores, simply try:

```
sed -i -r '/\/.\/. ::|:: |::foo|\^\^bar/d' file.txt
```

Also, you may want to consider escaping the `.` symbols. The dot would otherwise match any character.

HTH

Comment: the '_' are part of the expression I am searching for.

Comment: Also, running -ir doesn't seem to output the text even when I end with "2>&1". sending to "> output.txt" also doesn't produce output.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '{
s/::foo_//
s/\^\^bar//
s!/./. ::!!
s/:: _//
}' input_file
```

To totally delete lines containing patterns:

```
sed '{
/::foo_/d
/\^\^bar/d
\!/./. ::!d
/:: _/d
}' input_file
```

Comment: This will not delete the lines, it will only substitute the patterns with nothing. But the fix is easy; change each `s#pattern##` to `\#pattern#d` (the backslash is not necessary if the separator is forward slash; I used `#` as a placeholder for the separator character).

Comment: Oh, and the braces around the script are superfluous.

Comment: when I run this with or without braces, It gives an error: "extra characters after command".

Comment: @tripleee: I don't understand "\#pattern#d" would that be : sed '\::foo_d'?

Comment: @OcastaEshu, it is `/::foo_/d` or `\#::foo_#d`. Backslash is needed if you change the separator to something other than `/`.